# Alternative First() function for geometry type

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table with ID duplicates and I'm doing a group by for eliminating them. The unique values that are not groupeable are the values of the `geom` column (geometry type). For this column I tryied `FIRST ()` as agreggation method, but it outputs me this error:

> ERROR: the function first(geometry) does not exist.

I also tryied `MIN ()`function instead, but it outputs me the data of de column `geom` in text type.

Do you know any alternative for `FIRST ()` function to use at geometry type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `first()` function in Postgres.  You might be able to use `first_value()`:

```
select distinct col,
       first_value(geo) over (partition by col order by dt)
from t;
```

Or the array method should work:

```
select col,
       (array_agg(geo order by dt))[1]
from t
group by col
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. What do you mean with dt?

Comment: @J.Patordi . . . You say you want the "first", that must be based on some column.

Comment: I don't care the geom value to take, i just want one of them for eliminate the duplicate. I just put the ID column and worked. Thanks a lot!